# Gitlab webhook giving 503 while testing push for jenkins integration

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

[image: 1]

I know the jenkins URL needs a proxy to connect and I think my gitlab need some proxy for push events for testing purpose. **But I dont know that how can i call the jenkins hook with proxy from gitlab.**

I am getting 503 response with some html which is saying about connection refused while testing the hook from gitlab.

My jenkins is able to give SUCCESS response while setting up the gitlab connection but from gitlab to jenkins I am getting 503 with connection refused.

Comment: Can you please provide more context to your problem? Any connection strings or pipelines

Comment: I have added a screenshot now